# Можно ли добавить значение в бд просто присвоив значение атрибуту?

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

В процессе изучения у меня появилось несколько вопросов(без привязки к фреимворку):

1. Атрибут(поле) отображается в столбец этого же типа. Столбец - это несколько значений. Какое тогда значение у атрибута?
2. Что будет, если я просто присвою значение атрибуту?
3. Можно ли добавить значение в столбец просто присвоив значение атрибуту?
4. А если нет, то что случится когда я присвою значение атрибуту?
5. И зачем нужны геттеры/сеттеры, если для вставки значений в бд используется JPQL?

Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Прочтите любую книгу по `Java Persistence API` или `Hibernate` и с легкостью ответите на данные вопросы.

Comment: @notaProgrammer а так ответить нельзя? Я и так читаю, но пока ответы на эти вопросы не нашел.

Comment: Ответить, конечно, можно. Но, поскольку вопросы слишком общие, прийдется много писать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если под несколькими значениями подразумевается несколько строк с разными значениями в столбце, то в этом случае будет несколько объектов, а значение аттрибута объекта будет соответствовать значению в соответствующей строке.
2. Если объект, у которого изменяется аттрибут, привязан к живой сессии JPA или Hibernate, то изменение попадёт в БД. В противном случае в БД ничего не изменится.
3. Если объект новый - нет, нужно сохранить объект при помощи одного из методов `persist`, `save`, `merge` или `saveOrUpdate` интерфейса `org.hibernate.Session` или `merge` или `persist` интерфейса `javax.persistence.EntityManager`. Если объект существует, то возможно развитие ситуации из п.2, но может потребоваться вызов одного из указанных методов, если объект не привязан к живой сессии.
4. Ничего не случится
5. Hibernate может обращаться к свойствам как напрямую, так и при помощи get/set-методов. [Документация](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch02.html).

Очень рекомендую прочитать документацию по JPA и Hibernate и/или книгу [Java Persistence API и Hibernate](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/147137095/)

Comment: Спасибо! Про первый вопрос: что значит несколько объектов? Вот у меня есть поле id, а есть столбец id. В столбце значения 1, 2, 3. Какое тогда будет значение у поля id?

Comment: @Алексей  Допустим у вас есть поле `private Long id`, в столбце никак не может быть `1, 2, 3`. В столбце будет только одно значение.

Comment: @Алексей, данные в РСУБД хранятся в виде таблиц, состоящих из столбцов и строк. Строки проецируются на код в виде объектов некоторого класса, столбцы - в виде свойств этого класса. Если в таблице есть колонка id, то предполагается, что класс, на который спроецирована структура таблицы, тоже содержит свойство id. Соответственно, если в таблице 3 строки, то Hibernate/JPA при запросе может вернуть 3 объекта, у каждого из которых значение свойства id будет своё.

Comment: @АлександрКосарев вы этим многое объяснили, спасибо. Т.е., при запросе `SELECT e.id FROM Entity AS e;` он возвращает 3 объекта Entity и у каждого разные id? А остальные поля одинаковые, и будут ли они вообще, а если да - то чему они равны?

Comment: @АлександрКосарев т.е. на одну таблицу не один объект Entity, а несколько? А я думал что на одну таблицу один объект с разными значениями для поля.

Comment: @Алексей, всё верно, 3 строки в таблице = 3 объекта при таком запросе.  Значения всех свойств соответствуют значениям столбцов в соответствующих строках.

Comment: @АлександрКосарев у меня появился еще один вопрос. Вот если у меня у одного Entity есть поле-экземпляр другого Entity. Они как то связаны в самой бд, или только в JPA? А если связаны в бд, то как именно? Через REFERENCES? И точно такой же вопрос по спискам - они тоже как то связаны в бд, или только в JPA?